# VBA If, elseif statement, how to set a constant when the first IF statement is not met

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I have a If, Elseif, Else statement. If the first If is met I would like to plug in calculated values for runoff and percolation. However, if the first IF condition is not met, runoff and percolation will always get assigned 0's. I have pasted my code below. The problem I am having is that if I set percolation and runoff=0 after the first IF statement, my print sub will always print 0's, not the calculated values. How can I assign runoff and percolation as constants if the first IF condition is not met? I know I can just assign the runoff=0, percolation=0 in each subsequent condition, but I am trying to reduce the bulkiness of my code.

```
 Do
         If (fc - WC(j - 1) + RefET(i)) <= Precip(i) Then
                WC(j) = fc
                WCinit(j) = WC(j)
                Runoff(j - 1) = (Precip(i) - (fc - WC(j - 1) + RefET(i))) * 0.5
                Percolation(j - 1) = (Precip(i) - (fc - WC(j - 1) + RefET(i))) * 0.5
'    Runoff(j - 1) = 0 <-If I assign these here, it "overrides" the value I calculated on the previous line. I want to reduce the bulkiness of my code by assigning these values if the first IF condition is not met
'    Percolation(j - 1) = 0
          ElseIf (WC(j - 1) + Precip(i) - RefET(i)) > pwp Then
                 WC(j) = WC(j - 1) + Precip(i) - RefET(i)
                 WCinit(j) = WC(j)
                 Runoff(j - 1) = 0
                 Percolation(j - 1) = 0
        Else
                WC(j) = pwp
                WCinit(j) = WC(j)
                Runoff(j - 1) = 0
                Percolation(j - 1) = 0
        End If
                j = j + 1
                i = i + 1
                Loop While j < 14
```

Comment: Assign the runoff=0, percolation=0 before the first if statement.

Comment: But, I if the condition is met on the first IF statement, I do not want them to equal 0, but equal a calculated value, only if the 2 and 3 condition are met do they equal 0. If I set them to 0 before the first IF statement, they will always return 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or when you dimention them.  Dim Percolation as int = 0

Comment: This is not VB.Net :) Also setting the variable outside the `Do Loop` will not set it's value to `0` for the second round :)